# Can't convert YUV video with ffmpeg

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, yuv

When i try to convert a file with ffmpeg (from command prompt) it always gives me:

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

The file name is `left_432x240.yuv` and I have downloaded it from [here](http://sp.cs.tut.fi/mobile3dtv/stereo-video/).

the command i do is:

```
ffmpeg -f rawvideo -vcodec rawvideo -s 432x240 -r 25 -pix_fmt yuv420p -i left_432x240.yuv -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -qp 0 output.mp4
```

I have tried various option combination, but the result is always the same.

doing:
    ffmpeg -i left_432x240.yuv

produce:

```
ffmpeg version 2.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Nov 28 2013 16:44:43 with gcc 4.8 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.8.1-10ubuntu9)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-libfaac --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --enable-nonfree --enable-postproc --enable-version3 --enable-x11grab
  libavutil      52. 48.100 / 52. 48.100
  libavcodec     55. 39.100 / 55. 39.100
  libavformat    55. 19.104 / 55. 19.104
  libavdevice    55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100
  libavfilter     3. 90.100 /  3. 90.100
  libswscale      2.  5.101 /  2.  5.101
  libswresample   0. 17.104 /  0. 17.104
  libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
[IMGUTILS @ 0xbff1adc0] Picture size 0x0 is invalid
[IMGUTILS @ 0xbff1a8d0] Picture size 0x0 is invalid
[IMGUTILS @ 0xbff1a950] Picture size 0x0 is invalid
[rawvideo @ 0xa2aaee0] Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Video: rawvideo (I420 / 0x30323449), yuv420p, -4 kb/s): unspecified size
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
left_432x240.yuv: could not find codec parameters
```

Comment: ffmpeg -i left_432x240.yuv      what does that do on ur system?

Comment: Sorry for the naive question but how do you expect the playback of a stereo video to occur? 16 parallel windows/tiled/...? I don't think you can do this with ffmpeg.

Comment: each video contains information of only one view.

Comment: @RobertRowntree The warnings are to be expected with raw yuv input.

Comment: Which sample file is it exactly? There are many named `left_432x240.yuv` on the FTP server.

Comment: i tried with all of them, but you can find it in /Mobile_3DTV/HHI/Alt_moabit